RDKit- How can we print problematic molecules and their issues together?
I got the error messages using RDKit.Chem.
[14:21:42] Can't kekulize mol.  Unkekulized atoms: 3 5 6 7 9 10
[14:21:42] Can't kekulize mol.  Unkekulized atoms: 3 5 6 7 10 11
[14:21:48] Explicit valence for atom # 2 O, 3, is greater than permitted
[14:21:48] Explicit valence for atom # 2 O, 3, is greater than permitted

My expectations of the results are like these:
Can't kekulize **molecule A**.
Explicit valence for atom # 2 O, 3, is greater than permitted in **Molecule B**.

How can I print out the specific molecules causing the errors above?
I am trying to sanitize the molecules, so I need to identify which molecules are problematic.

Please edit your question and add the code you're using. In case you're looping over molecules, add the code for the entire loop.

You are presumably building the molecules from SMILES strings or something related. You can then just use try and except, to catch the erroneous molecules and then print them to console or otherwise handle them.
